# Expressing a Vector in a new Basis

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

This is the first time I have attempted such a problem, and have been tackling it all morning. I've been trying to use simultaneous equations to solve for the variables, but it doesn't seem to be working out, so perhaps that's not the way to go...

$$\hat{\bf a} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{14}}({\bf i}+2{\bf j}+3{\bf k})$$
$$\hat{\bf b} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(2{\bf i}-{\bf j})$$
$$\hat{\bf c} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{70}}(3{\bf i}+6{\bf j}-5{\bf k})$$

Express the vector ${\bf d} = 5{\bf i}+3{\bf j}+2{\bf k}$ in the new $(\hat{\bf a},\hat{\bf b},\hat{\bf c})$ basis.

My attempted solution can be seen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8CnEriPXOd1T3Z1amU4UGlMVU0/view

There is basic arithmetic mistake in my attempted answer, so I have answered my own question below. Sorry for wasting anybody's time; I'll try to be more careful.

Comment: Do you know change of basis matrices?

Comment: @Bernard, I don't, but I have a basic understanding of matrices, so it's certainly something I could look into if it's likely to yield a solution.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, but there's no way around it. You'll need to solve a system of equations to find your coordinate vector. As Bernard hints, you could find a change of basis matrix. It's easy to write one down which changes from your new coordinates into standard coordinates, but that's the wrong direction. You'd need to compute the inverse of such a matrix (which you're right back to solving systems.

Answer (score 2):

we will first deal with expressing as a linear combination of $\sqrt{14}\hat a, \sqrt 5\hat b,$ and $\sqrt{70}\hat c.$
we need number $x, y, z$ so that $$x(i+2j+3k)+y(2i-j)+z(3i+6j-5k)=5i+3j+2k \tag 1  $$ 
in matrix form, we have $$\pmatrix{1&2&3&|&5\\2&-1&6&|&3\\3&0&-5&|&2}\to 
\pmatrix{1&0&0&|&1.21428\\0&1&0&|&1.40000\\0&0&1&|&0.32857}$$
the solutions $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ is the last column in the second matrix. now, multiplying $x,y,z$ by $\sqrt{14}, \sqrt{5}, \sqrt{70}$ gives you the answer.

Comment: In case someone can't have the insight into @Abel's method at the very first glance like me, I explain it a bit here: His method is equivalent to solve this system of equations $\pmatrix{1&2&3&|&x\\2&-1&6&|&y\\3&0&-5&|&z}=\pmatrix{5\\3\\2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Wow, after all of that, and what I had believed to be a meticulous examination of my work, I rechecked it in the morning after some refreshing sleep, and found a basic arithmetic mistake. Theta should have been (17 x rt(14))/14. Sorry to have wasted anybody's time!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for $[r,s,t]$ where $r\hat{\bf a}+s\hat{\bf b}+t\hat{\bf c}=5{\bf i}+3{\bf j}+2{\bf k}$.

This means that $\dfrac{r}{\sqrt{14}}+\dfrac{2s}{\sqrt{5}}+\dfrac{3t}{\sqrt{70}}=5$ (the coefficients of ${\bf i}$). Same for the coefficients of ${\bf j}$ and ${\bf k}$. Then it's just a matter of slugging through this rather unattractive system of equations. :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm going to need to invest some time in learning how to properly write my equations on here, but I've typed up my attempted solution, and saved it as a pdf on Google Drive if you wouldn't mind taking a look. I hope it's followable. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8CnEriPXOd1T3Z1amU4UGlMVU0/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

so you are looking for [$\alpha, \beta, \gamma$] where $\vec b = \alpha \hat a + \beta \hat b + \gamma \hat c =5\hat i+3\hat j+2\hat k$.

By rules of vectors, if you project $\vec b$ onto $\hat i$, you get the value of that unit vector only, which would be 5 in this case.

mathmatically it looks like this

$\vec d   ⋅\hat i = ( 5\hat i\hat i ) + ( 2\hat j\hat i) + ( 3\hat k\hat i )$

where $\hat i\hat i = 1$   and   $ \hat j\hat i = \hat k\hat i = 0$

so,
$\vec d   ⋅\hat i = 5 \times 1 = 5$

we can then do the same with each unit vector you have in your new basis

$\vec d   ⋅\hat a = \frac{1}{\sqrt14}(5\times1 + 3\times2 + 2\times3) =\frac{17}{\sqrt14} = \alpha$

$\vec d   ⋅\hat b =  \frac{1}{\sqrt5}(5\times2 + 3\times-1 + 2\times0) =\frac{7}{\sqrt5} = \beta$

$\vec d   ⋅\hat c =  \frac{1}{\sqrt70}(5\times3 + 3\times6 + 2\times-5) = \frac{23}{\sqrt70} = \gamma$

Finally we can say that vector $\vec b$ with unit basis $(\hat a, \hat b, \hat c)$ is equal to

$\vec d  = \frac{17}{\sqrt14} \hat a + \frac{7}{\sqrt5} \hat b + \frac{23}{\sqrt70} \hat c$